# Bash variable sequence expansion (letter range)

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

Given a couple variables I'd like to concatenate:

```
# valid
COUNTRIES_A="ad,af,ai,ag,al,am,ao,ar,ax,az,"
COUNTRIES_B="ba,bd,bf,bh,bi,bj,bn,br,bt,bw"

COUNTRIES="${COUNTRIES_A},${COUNTRIES_B}"
```

is there a sequence expansion that can achieve this a bit more elegantly?

```
# invalid but essentially ...
COUNTRIES="${COUNTRIES_{A..B}}"
```

Comment: I believe code readability to be massively important as a software engineer. You can easily see how this improves a fairly trivial script here: https://gist.github.com/mtompkins/f43ef38f2b3a7263650d212e49e8a498

Comment: You are confusing "elegance" with "minimalism". I would use the first approach without hesitation.

Comment: @chepner There is no confusion whatsoever and I couldn't disagree with you more strongly.

Comment: I wasn't actually referring to your code, but having looked at it, it raises the question: why are you using separate `COUNTRIES_X` variables, when all you do with them is concatenate them into a single variable. You could just define a single *array* to store a list of strings in the first place, and an array assignment can group entries by lines for readability.

Comment: Two reasons - 1) it allows a quick visual inspection to see if a current country is in the list (e.g. INDIA / in) can be spotted much quicker than visually examining a very long array. Granted this can be improved if the array is maintained in sequence but that's overhead. 2) it allows for `sed` optimization. Traversing an array vs. traversing a subset of one as in `O(n^x)`

Comment: If you are doing anything with an array in `bash` other than iterating over it, you are using the wrong language.

Comment: Terribly specious comment - I'm done with the discourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
$ echo $COUNTRIES_{A..B}

ad,af,ai,ag,al,am,ao,ar,ax,az ba,bd,bf,bh,bi,bj,bn,br,bt,bw
```

so, you can do

```
$ COUNTRIES=$(echo $COUNTRIES_{A..B})
```

if you want a full csv list, pipe to `tr ' ' ','`

Comment: Darn, I should have thought of this - exactly what I wanted. Simply expand and assign the variable / string before later use. Bravo!

Comment: Minor add here - whitespace needs mitigation so please consider updating above to $ `COUNTRIES=$(echo $COUNTRIES_{A..B})| tr -d '[:space:]'`

Comment: Removing space might have bad consequences if your original strings had spaces in them.  Your intent is to have a comma between the two, right?

Comment: @codeforester - correct, the whitespace management is particular to the example given in this case. The expected output should have no additions of whitespace which will happen with the given solution in its current form.

Comment: I can't recommend this approach. There's no way to correctly quote the resulting parameter expansions.

Comment: In fact, the resultant parameter expansion can be correctly quoted without issue and is in use in the above-referenced script.

Comment: No, it isn't. The shell expands `$COUNTRIES_A` and `$CONTRIES_B` and applies word-splitting before passing the values to `echo`. The fact that the result of the `echo` command doesn't undergo further word-splitting is irrelevant; any damage has already been done.

Comment: Demonstrate something equivalent to `echo "$COUNTRY_A" "$COUNTRY_B"` instead of `echo $COUNTRY_A $COUNTRY_B`, and I will happily up vote.

Comment: this is obviously not a generic solution, if you're not preserving any white space and not case about logical grouping of the contents quotation is not necessary as in this particular case.